# When does Spymemcached's MemcachedClient#delete return false?

Tags: java, memcached, spymemcached

I'm using Spymemcached (2.10.0), and I would like to know when `MemcachedClient#delete(String key)` returns false.

I already found `MemcachedClient#delete(String key)` fails and returns false when the specified key is not found, but I don't know whether it happens in any other situations.

Reference document says nothing about the returned value...

http://dustin.sallings.org/java-memcached-client/apidocs/net/spy/memcached/MemcachedClient.html

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only two return codes you get from a failed delete are "not found" and "exists". The not found error code (`KEY_ENOENT`) is returned when the deleted key is not in the cache. The exists `KEY_EXISTS` is returned when the delete fails due to the cas value being incorrect. To get more information on why a particular operation failed you can call `getStatus().getStatusCode()` on the `OperationFuture` returned by the `delete()` function.